How to write a test and set a value of variable with vue-test-utils?
I have a method in my component that is triggered when the user click the button. The problem that i have is that im getting an error and i dont know what i am doing wrong.
This is the method in my component:
updateCecos() {
      console.log("updateCecos")
      this.valid = this.$refs.formCeco.validate()
      if (this.valid) {
        this.sendUpdateCecos()
      } else {
        this.$emit("update:pendingChangesCecos", false)
        this.showError(
          this.$t("lang.vista-peticion-datosBasicos.errorFormularioInvalido")
        )
      }
    },

And this is the test that i made to evaluate the method:
describe("Ceco.vue", () => {
  let localVue
  let vuetify
  let wrapper
  let $route
  let store
  let changed
  let sendUpdateCecos

  beforeEach(() => {
    // se inicializa vue
    localVue = createLocalVue()
    // se hace un mock de la ruta actual
    $route = {
      path: "/maestroProyectos",
    }
    // se inicializa la store
    localVue.use(Vuex)
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: mockStore.state,
      getters: mockStore.getters,
      actions: mockStore.actions,
      mutations: mockStore.mutations,
    })
    // se inicializa el traductor
    localVue.use(i18n)
    // se inicializa vuetify
    Vue.use(Vuetify)
    vuetify = new Vuetify()
    // se espian los metodos del componente
    changed = jest.spyOn(Cecos.methods, "changed")
    sendUpdateCecos = jest.spyOn(Cecos.methods, "sendUpdateCecos")
    // se monta el componente en la variable wrapper
    wrapper = mount(Cecos, {
      localVue,
      store,
      vuetify,
      i18n,
      propsData: {
        newProyecto: false,
        editProyecto: false,
        mapDataFromTable: new Map(),
        listaCecos: [{text: "1", value: "1"}],
        loadingCompleteHttp: false,
        thereAreChangesCecos: false,
        pendingChangesCecos: false,
        tabPending: null,
      },
    })
  })

it("must call sendUpdateCecos method when button is clicked", async () => {
    await wrapper.setData({valid: true})
    expect(wrapper.vm.valid).toBe(true)

    const button = wrapper.find(".slide-secondary-btn")
    button.trigger("click")

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

    await flushPromises()

    expect(sendUpdateCecos).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })
})

The problem is that i get the next error when running the test:
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      174 |     await flushPromises()
      175 |
    > 176 |     expect(sendUpdateCecos).toHaveBeenCalled()
          |                             ^
      177 |     // expect(actions.showError).toHaveBeenCalled()
      178 |   })
      179 |

      at toHaveBeenCalled (test/components/MaestroProyectos/Cecos.spec.js:176:29)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:45:16)
      at Generator.<anonymous> (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:133:17)
      at Generator.next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:74:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:17)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:9)

What could be the reason for the test to fail?

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's not evident that updateCecos is called, add an assertion for the call. It's not evident that wrapper.vm.valid is true inside of the method. That you're mocking it instead of assuring that this.valid = this.$refs.formCeco.validate() is true suggests that it's not
